# Creating contour plot from Pandas multi-index dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, multi-index, contour

How do I create a contour plot from the following Pandas dataframe named think_or_feel:

```
              think     feel
cNEU    cOPN        
y         n     27      20
n         n     40      23
y         y     43      25
n         y     97      63
```

I have tried the following:

```
X=think_or_feel.columns
Y=think_or_feel.index 
Z=think_or_feel.values
x,y=np.meshgrid(X, Y)
plt.contourf(x,y,Z)
```

I get the following error:
`unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`

I'd really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: If you share runnable code, it will be easier for people to help.

Comment: @swatchai OP is asking **why** the provided code is not running.

Comment: @QuangHoang I meant minimum runnable code, including the code that creates the dataframe and etc.

Comment: @swatchai The dataframe included is just fine. You can copy it and do `pd.read_clipboard()` on most system.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks for the useful hint. But it does't work on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the reason is that your index/columns are not numbers, while `plt.contourf` expects numbers. Let's try:

```
X=np.arange(think_or_feel.shape[1])
Y=np.arange(think_or_feel.shape[0])
Z=think_or_feel.values

plt.contourf(x,y,Z)
plt.xticks(X, think_or_feel.columns)
plt.yticks(Y, think_or_feel.index)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Very helpful. Appreciate it. Thank you!